# How to put images appear side by side in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, object-detection

I have this object detection program where the user gives an image and chooses a model to make the detection and it shows on the tkinter as shown on the pics:

https://prnt.sc/wa1mu2

https://prnt.sc/wa1nu1

https://prnt.sc/wa1o7t

I am trying to make a command called compare where the user presses it,chooses an image and shows both pics side by side.I can tell that it will need try,except to avoid any errors.Also I am trying to make a command reset where it makes the window go back to its starting point.My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import messagebox


def object_det_MobileNetSSD():
    # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", default=img1)
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt")
    ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel")
    ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2)
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    # initialize the list of class labels MobileNet SSD was trained to
    # detect, then generate a set of bounding box colors for each class
    CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
        "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
        "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
        "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
    COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))

    # load our serialized model from disk
    print("[INFO] loading model...")
    model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

    # load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
    # by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
    # (note: normalization is done via the authors of the MobileNet SSD
    # implementation)
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
    # predictions
    print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
    model.setInput(blob)
    detections = model.forward()

    # loop over the detections
    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
        # prediction
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
            # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # display the prediction
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
            print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
            cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
                COLORS[idx], 2)
            y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
            cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    width, height = image.size
    if int(width)<int(height): img = image.resize((400, 555), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    else: img = image.resize((900, 555), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel.config(image=img)
    panel.image=img
    
def object_det_Yolo():
        config_file="ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
        frozen_model="frozen_inference_graph.pb"
        model=cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(frozen_model,config_file)
        Labels=[]
        file_name="labels.txt"
        with open(file_name,"rt") as fpt:
                Labels= fpt.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n") 

        model.setInputSize(320,320)
        model.setInputScale(1.0/127.5)
        model.setInputMean((127.5,127.5,127.5))
        model.setInputSwapRB(True)
        img=cv2.imread(img1) 
        ClassIndex,confidence,bbox=model.detect(img,confThreshold=0.5)
        for ClassInd,conf,boxes in zip(ClassIndex.flatten(),confidence.flatten(),bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img,boxes,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(img,Labels[ClassInd-1].upper(),(boxes[0]+10,boxes[1]+30),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,100,0),2)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        width, height = img.size
        if int(width)<int(height): img = img.resize((400, 555), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        else: img = img.resize((900, 555), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        panel.config(image=img)
        panel.image=img

def compare():
        pass

def reset():
        pass

def check_checkbox1() :
    global val1
    val1=is_checked1.get()
    if val1== 1:
        is_checked2.set(0)
    return val1

def check_checkbox2():
    global val2
    val2=is_checked2.get()
    if val2 == 1:
        is_checked1.set(0)
    return val2



def model_choice():
    check_checkbox1()
    check_checkbox2()
    if val1==1: object_det_MobileNetSSD()
    elif val2==1: object_det_Yolo()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Choose a model")


def callback():
        global img1
        img1= filedialog.askopenfilename()
        model_choice()
    
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Object Detection")
root.resizable(False, False)
is_checked1 = tk.IntVar()
is_checked2 = tk.IntVar()
is_checked3 = tk.IntVar()
window_height = 670
window_width = 1000
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))
root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate-45, y_cordinate-45))
root.configure(background='grey')
menubar=tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)
selection=tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Detection Models",menu=selection)
selection.add_checkbutton(label="MobileNet",onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = is_checked1, command = check_checkbox1)
selection.add_checkbutton(label="YOLO",onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = is_checked2, command = check_checkbox2)
commandbar=tk.Menu(menubar)
selection2=tk.Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Commands",menu=selection2)
selection2.add_command(label="Compare",command=compare)
selection2.add_command(label="Reset",command=reset)
w1=tk.Label(root,text="Object detection",font = "Impact 36", bg ='lightgray', width = 900, borderwidth=4, relief="solid")
w1.pack(fill="x")
panel = tk.Label(root,bg="grey")
panel.pack()
button=tk.Button(root,text="Choose image",font = "Impact 17", fg = "lightgray", highlightbackground="lightgray", bg ="black",command=callback)
button.pack()
button.place(x=390,y=625)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Start with a simpler example, focusing on just the UI.  Use `Image.new('RGB', (100,100), 'red')` to create test images.  Then, you can post small example here for more help.

Comment: what is your problem?  You can use `grid()` to put two elements in one line - ie two `labels` for two `images`. Or you can use `pillow` (or `numpy array`) to join two images into one image.

Comment: eventually you can use `.pack(side='left',...)`, `.pack(side='right', ...)` like in [example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/resize-image-in-background) but using `frame` with two `labels` and `grid()` can be simpler.